# How does Thread.sleep really work?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sleep, event-dispatch-thread

I've made a program that sets a button's `setEnable` from time to time. The `Thread.sleep()` is in another class. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Try extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton n1 = new JButton("1");
JButton n2 = new JButton("2");
JButton n3 = new JButton("3");
JButton show = new JButton("Show");

{
show.addActionListener(this);
n1.setEnabled(false);
n2.setEnabled(false);
n3.setEnabled(false);

}

public Try(){
  super("Try");
  setVisible(true);
  setSize(500, 200);
  setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
  add(n1);
  add(n2);
  add(n3);
  add(show);
}  

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
Object clicked = a.getSource();
if(show == clicked){
new EasyLevel1().start();
}
}

  class EasyLevel1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {      
        try {
            n1.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n1.setEnabled(false);
            n2.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n2.setEnabled(false);
            n3.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n3.setEnabled(false);    
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        }
      }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Try frame = new Try();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

However, when I put it on my `actionListener` within the class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Try extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton n1 = new JButton("1");
JButton n2 = new JButton("2");
JButton n3 = new JButton("3");
JButton show = new JButton("Show");

{
show.addActionListener(this);
n1.setEnabled(false);
n2.setEnabled(false);
n3.setEnabled(false);

}

public Try(){
  super("Try");
  setVisible(true);
  setSize(500, 200);
  setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
  add(n1);
  add(n2);
  add(n3);
  add(show);
}  

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
Object clicked = a.getSource();
if(show == clicked){
            try {n1.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n1.setEnabled(false);
            n2.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n2.setEnabled(false);
            n3.setEnabled(true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            n3.setEnabled(false);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Try frame = new Try();
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

It freezes my whole program, based from that example I've understood that a thread sleep should be ran in another thread to stop the current class from freezing. But I expected the new thread.sleep with still freeze its operations like it will still do the code above but the buttons will be responsive since its in another thread. But surprisingly it did what I wanted it to do, It didn't instantly set everything to disabled like the first program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that in the 2nd example `Thread.sleep` is blocking the `EDT` so no further UI updates occur. In contrast, in the first example you are calling `sleep` in a separare `Thread` so no "freezing" occurs. For tasks like this the use of [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) is preferred.

Comment: No problem, do have a look at the `Swing Timers` :)

Comment: Yeah, while i've chosen thread.sleep because Its easier for me, I'm currently studying the link you gave me to help me understand them. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.sleep()` makes the current thread pause. You are running it in an `actionPerformed`, that is in a Swing Event. All Swing operations are done in a single thread, the EDT. When you pause it with a Thread.sleep(), Swing can not handle any other event because you haven't returned from the actionPerformed listener. Therefore, the GUI freezes (not the complete application, just the GUI).

In general, it is bad practice to do long-running actions in a Swing event because of this. For what you are trying to do, the good alternative is to use Swing timers.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep` will cause the thread that executes the call to sleep for the specified time (or until the thread is interrupted). When you call it in the `actionPerformed` method, it causes the UI thread to sleep. That's why your program is locking up.

You should start a separate thread that will step through the various calls you want to make while sleeping in between. Alternatively (and much better, in my opinion) you could use [Swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks it really cleared up alot in my mind, so its really doing what I want in the second example, but, as thread slept it also slept my gui code so it "frooze because my gui is also sleeping" and became responsive after the sleep because its no longer sleeping. That's it right?

Comment: @JerlyTuazon - Exactly. If you use swing timers to schedule the various `setEnabled` calls, your gui will not lock up.

Comment: I've got a question tho, but its not related with "freezing" but it involves thread.sleep. Why does thread.sleep always have an InterruptedException problem? I mean they've explained it as when the the sleeping gets disturbed or something. But i've tried leaving only 1 line to be executed by thread and its Thread.sleep but it still says InterruptedException, as far as I know my thread.sleep didn't go off prematurely or has been disturbed?

Comment: @JerlyTuazon - Sometimes, in a multi-threaded app, you want one thread to signal another that it should stop what it's doing. The signaling thread can call the `interrupt()` method of the other thread to do that. The other thread should be written to check its interrupt flag (using `isInterrupted()`). However, when it's sleeping, it obviously can't do that. But when a sleeping thread's `interrupt()` method is called, the `sleep()` call exits prematurely with an `InterruptedException`. This is not a "problem"--it's a feature: you've just been told (by another thread in your program) to exit.

Comment: @JerlyTuazon One way this "interrupt feature" might be used in your specific application would be to handle cases where the user clicks "Show" again during the (current thread's) cascading button work.  If you wanted the cascade to "reset," it might make sense to interrupt the current thread's work so you could restart it in a new thread.  Of course this is more of a conceptual thinking exercise; when you migrate to Swing Timers I believe that there's a timer stop feature.

Comment: @JerlyTuazon - If one of the posted answers solved your problem, you should mark it as the solution (by clicking on the outlined check mark next to the answer). This lets other know what worked for you, rewards the responders with some rep, and gives you a little rep boost as well. You should also upvote answers that were useful to you (by clicking on the up-pointing triangle next to the answer). For one answer, of course, you could do both. :)

Comment: Oh Ted, why does another thread interrupt another? I didn't even declare an interrupt in my code? What is the code in my program that interrupts my thread sleep? I'm just really curious since i've asked my friends and they just said that's just the way java is but I really wanna understand it.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot the check thing, and bout the triangle it says I need 15 reps

Comment: @JerlyTuazon - One thread won't interrupt another unless you program it to do so. Since the compiler doesn't know whether you will do so or not, it requires that you catch an `InterruptedException` (or declare that your code will throw it) whenever you call `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Oh I get it, so whether you like it or not, you'll have to catch InterruptedException as a precautionary measure if ever you'll interrupt it? even if you don't use it the compiler needs it? Am I right or i'm still missing something?

Comment: Cool thanks alot bro, my mind is at rest in this topic now. Thanks